# Como invocar Resources visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb, vb6

Buen dia

Quisiera saber como puedo tomar un archivo que guarde en Resources llamado "config.dat" ,para ejecutarlo ya que aplicaria una configuracion en una impresora, tengo el siguiente timer que da unas acciones dependiendo del valor

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick_2(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 105 Then
        Shell("cmd.exe /c rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n " + nombre)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 110 Then
        Shell("cmd.exe /c control printers")
        Application.ExitThread()
    End If
    Label7.Text = ProgressBar1.Value & (" %")
End Sub
```

deseo ejecutar la siguiente instruccion, pero no se como puedo tomar ese archivo "config.dat" si ya esta guardado en mi proyecto en la carpeta Resources

```
 shell("cmd.exe /C rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry/Sr /n "impresora" /a "config.dat"")
```

Alguien sabe como hacerlo

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Asi quedaria en vb6

```
Shell "cmd.exe /C rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry/Sr /n " & "'impresora' /a " & App.Path & "\Resources\config.dat"
```

Comment: Hola, aunque esta respuesta puede ser de utilidad, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad (es básicamente código sin ninguna explicación, lo que no suele ser de mucha ayuda para otros usuarios). Por favor, edita tu publicación para añadir una descripción con lo que hace el código y cómo soluciona el problema de la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información.